# Elasticsearch restore to a new cluster with differnt number of nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, restore

I have a ops cluster with 5 nodes (1 master, 1 client, and 3 data nodes).  I want to restore a backup of this onto a new test cluster with only 3 nodes (1 master, 1 client, 1 data).   I only have 1 data node in my test cluster at the moment and wasn't planning to add any additional data nodes on my test cluster.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to restore to my test cluster, only some of the shards get assigned.  Most of them stay in the UNASSIGNED state.  I've tried to use the reroute api but it fails.  See below

Does my test cluster have to have the same number of nodes as my ops cluster I'm restoring from?  If so is there any work around for this?

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "reroute_transport_exception",
        "reason": ["myhost_master"[myhostip:9200][cluster:admin/reroute]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "resovled [myhostip] into [3] nodes, where excpeted to be resolved to a single node"
  ],
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: How many replicas does the original set have? I'm guessing that the replicas cannot be assigned in your test cluster as there is only one data node.

Comment: Most of my indices have only 1 some have 2.  I thought that during a restore, the mappings from the ops cluster will be added to the backup cluster.

Comment: And how exactly can one node ensure the redundancy that the replicas concept entails? As you mention you have only one data node, you will need at least two to distribute the replicas (they can only be located on a data node)

Comment: I failed to mention that since my original post, I did start up 3 data nodes in my backup cluster and I ensured that the mapping was set the same as the ops cluster. It seems to be restoring properly now.